# stopping page not found errors when controller does not exist

Tags: php, zend-framework

In production mode (minimal errors), when a controller is not found, Zend gives a 404 page not found error. There are a couple of controllers that I don't want this activated for. Even though they don't exist, I don't want the page not found error activated. Is it possible to somehow block that error and give an empty page. I'm guessing, if at all possible, it has to be done at the plugin level since no controller really exists to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to check the request object in your `errorAction` for controller and/or action that threw the exceptions (for non-existing controllers and actions you could also get their names this way). Based on this you could customize the rest of errorAction. For example:

```
 public function errorAction() {
        $errors = $this->_getParam('error_handler');

        $whatController = $errors->request->getControllerName();

        if ('secretController' == $whatController) {
             return $this->_redirect('blankErrorPage');
        }

        // usual rest of errorAction
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to give it a try, but the issue I'm seeing is that it means I have to create a controller/action/view for `blankErrorPage`. Is there a way to get a view without a controller/action?

Comment: @jblue. You already have error.phtml view for errorAction. So, for example, instead of redirecting, just create some view variable, e.g. this->view->secret = true; and in the error.phtml display what you want based on this variable.